# Making my toggle button work with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize my browser and put it in mobile mode the button appears just fine. However, when i click on the button it does not drop the "home tab" which is what im trying to have drop. I was watching a video on youtube on how to do this but it was from 2013 and I think that is the problem. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Template1css.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Welcome</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the latest jQuery CDN before bootstrap js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the latest jQuery CDN before bootstrap js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Template1css.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Welcome</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.